# How does one output a new array, containing all numbers of a previous array that occur at most k times

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

How does one create a new array, containing all numbers of the array that occur at most k times in java?

For example, if the array was:

```
{1,4,4,3,4,3,5,2,5,1,5}
```

and `k = 2`, the new array would be:

```
{1,3,2}.
```

I assume that I would need to compare the elements within the arrays and add store the number of times it occurs as a variable. Then I would compare that variable to `k` and if it is smaller or equal to it, it will add it to a new arraylist. I can't really implement this tho.
Thanks

Comment: customization of frequency table problem!!

Comment: Is this homework? It's fine if it is, but it should have the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this, depending on what your constraints are.

If you don't need to worry about memory constraints, you can solve this problem quite easily by using a `HashMap` that maps from array elements to their frequencies.  The algorithm would work by scanning across the array.  For each element, if that element is already in the `HashMap`, you update the key/value pair in the `HashMap` to increment the frequency of that element.  Otherwise, if the element hasn't been seen, you update the frequency to be 1.  Once you've finished populating the `HashMap`, you can then iterate across the map and copy over all elements that have frequency at most `k` into a new `ArrayList`.  For example:

```
for(Map.Entry<T, Integer> entry: myMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() <= k)
        myArrayList.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

This runs in O(n) time and O(n) memory, which is quite good.

If you don't want to store everything in memory, another option would be to sort the array in O(n log n) time and O(log n) space using `Arrays.sort`.  Once you've sorted the array, all of the copies of each value will be stored consecutively and you can more easily count their frequency.  For example, after sorting the array you mentioned in your original post, you would get the array

```
1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

From here, it should be much easier to determine how many copies of each element there are.  You could do this by walking across the array, keeping track of the element you're currently looking for and how many copies there are.  Whenever you see a new element, if it matches the current element, you increment the counter.  If not, you reset the element you're checking to be the new element and set the counter back to one.  For example, with the above array, you might start off by looking at this element:

```
1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
^

Element: 1
Frequency: 1
```

Now, you look at the next element of the array.  Because it's a 1, you increment the frequency count to 2:

```
1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
  ^

Element: 1
Frequency: 2
```

When you look at the next element, you'll see that it's a 2.  This means that there aren't any more 1's left.  Because there are two copies of 1, you could then append 1 to the resulting array.  You'd then reset the counter to 1, leaving this state:

```
1 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
    ^

Element: 2
Frequency: 1
```

The one thing to watch out for when doing this is to remember to handle the case where you visit the final array element.  It's important that when you hit the end of the array, if you have at most `k` copies of the last element, you add the last number to the output array.

Whenever you do this, if you ever find an element that appears at most `k` times, you can add it to the new array.  This second step runs in O(n) time and O(m) space (where m is the total number of elements in the resulting array), so the total complexity is O(n log n) time and O(m + log n) space.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for completeness and not doing his entire homework assignment for him :)

Comment: The second way to do it is O(log n + m) space, where m is the output size.

Comment: The first solution(the map one) doesent run in O(n) time  as due to separate chaining in HashMap, the complexity becomes O(n^2)

Comment: @Suraj Chandran- While you're correct that in the worst-case the runtime is O(n^2), in the average case the behavior should be O(n), since the `HashMap` internally tries to keep a balanced load factor.

Comment: @akappa- Whoops, my mistake!  I've updated my answer to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two ways to do it:

1. Scan linearly the array, updating an hash table which stores the frequency of each encountered number (Average time: O(n), Space: O(n));
2. Sort the array and keeping a count of how many times you've seen the current element (which will be set to one every time the current number is different from the previous one). Time: O(n lg n), Space: O(m), where m is the number of returned element (assuming to use a O(1) space-complexity sorter, like heapsort).

The first one is time-optimal, the second one is space-optimal.